# Overlays in windows apps

Tags: c#

What's a good site to learn about creating overlays for windows applications? Books or other resources would be welcome as I am trying to understand the basic concepts. 
Specifically, if I have an application that diplays a video, how do I add overlay layer(s) with things like the person's name or a building's gps coordinates.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the CreateParams of your WinForm first:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= Win32.WS_EX_LAYERED; //Make this form a layered window
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you need to refresh your window, you need to call the `UpdateLayeredWindow` API.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern Bool UpdateLayeredWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdcDst, ref Point pptDst, ref Size psize, IntPtr hdcSrc, ref Point pprSrc, int crKey, ref BLENDFUNCTION pblend, int dwFlags);
```

See this [Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/perpxalpha_sharp.aspx) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to do what I want.